# Under what conditions would a Starfleet vessel be given the continuing mission of "boldly going where no one has gone before"?

Tags: star-trek

We know of at least three Enterprises (NX-01, NCC-1701, and NCC-1701 D) who had an ongoing mission to seek out new life and new civilisations etc. Thinking on it, it doesn't make much sense that only a single vessel at a time would have this ongoing mission, but it's also clear that some ships were not equipped for that kind of mission - the Defiant, for instance, was a warship while the Equinox was meant only for short-term exploration supported by starbases.

So, under what conditions would a ship be given that ongoing mission, and how many were there?

Answer (score 5):

**"To Boldly Go" is probably a Starfleet or Enterprise motto, not a mission-descriptor**

I don't think "To boldly go" (etc.) is a ship-specific mission type - I think it's a Starfleet slogan (the Mounties "Always get their man" but that doesn't mean a Mountie is always in pursuit, or that some Mounties are especially given pursuit missions).

In universe, the phrase comes from Cochrane's dedication of the NX-01

> On this site, a powerful engine will be built. An engine that will
> someday help us to travel a hundred times faster than we can today.
> Imagine it – thousands of inhabited planets at our fingertips... and
> we'll be able to explore those strange new worlds, and seek out new
> life and new civilizations. This engine will let us go boldly... where
> no man has gone before.

On the other hand, perhaps all *Enterprises* have that as their motto *because* Cochrane used that phrase when the first Enterprise was dedicated - US naval vessels often have mottos (the aircraft carrier USS Enterprise's motto was "We are Legend; Ready on Arrival; The First, the Finest; Eight Reactors, None Faster") that sound inspiring, but do not indicate anything special about each ship's likely missions. Kirk's Enterprise occasionally deliberately went where no human had been before, but many times it was sent to well-known regions (various Starbases) or at least to places where some people had been or were (M-113, Psi-2000, etc.); on several occasions, it was ferrying people from one known place to another (Vulcan to Babel, etc.).  There's no indication that Kirk's Enterprise spent the majority of its time (or even a significant minority of its time) exploring completely unknown areas (even when it went to the edge of the galaxy with Gary Mitchell, it was following the lead of another Earth vessel, and visits a Starfleet station on the way).

Out of universe, an earlier version of the [intro phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_no_man_has_gone_before) is

> This is the adventure of the United Space Ship Enterprise. Assigned a
> five year galaxy patrol, the bold crew of the giant starship explores
> the excitement of strange new worlds, uncharted civilizations, and
> exotic people. These are its voyages and its adventures...

which is much less emphatic about what the ship has been assigned to do.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about that. In the introduction to both ToS and TNG, both captains refer to their ship's mission and use that phrase

Comment: not bad at all, andrew.